# Is there a way to integrate synaptic with snap packages

Tags: synaptic, cinnamon, snap

Is there way to integrate synaptic package manager with snapd (snap packages)? Either when compiling from source or a .conf file? If not what is a package manager that will integrate with snap packages, Ubuntu repos and cinnamon 3.0.7?

Answer (score 4):

**GNOME Software** (also branded as **Ubuntu Software**) is the first, and so far only, app to support installing *snap* packages.

Synaptic is not receiving much development work at this time, but if someone did contribute a patch to add that feature, I'm sure it would be included if it worked.